# \psi gives different results?

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

[image][image]

I have two different Overleaf files from different people. Using `\psi` in the two documents gives different results. Any idea what could be the reason? I prefer the first one.

---

Following help from other people, I found this line `\RequirePackage{mathptm}` in the 2nd file and removed it which solved the problem.

Comment: One of the two files is loading a font package.

Comment: why make us guess? the fonts used will be set up in the preamble start from a copy of the document delete everything but this character then delete anything from the preamble you can delete without changing the output.

Comment: thanks the 2nd file had this line `\RequirePackage{mathptm}`. Commenting it fixed the problem.

Comment: This is known as "uncertainty principle". 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are both lowercase psi: the only difference between these two symbols is the font used, and the fact that the second is upright instead of italic.

The first is an italic lowercase psi in Computer Modern, the default font used in LaTeX. The following example outputs it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\(\psi\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second is an upright lowercase psi in a Times clone, as obtained with `txfonts`. The following example outputs it. The package `txgreeks` loads `txfonts` and allows to easily set the lowercase greek letters upright.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upgreek]{txgreeks}
\begin{document}
\(\psi\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As fourier does by default.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\usepackage{mathptmx}` from your .sty file!